# Python String Slicing with Paramiko Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice, paramiko

Hi I'm building a python app that will simplify managing multiple Raspberry Pi's on my network. The idea is that it will speed up basic tasks like updates on the Pi's by issuing the commands to the Pi via the paramiko python module. I can save commands to the application and then run them via a simple shortcut rather than having to login and type them out.

I've hit a bit of a stumbling block in that my commands are running and I'm getting the output but because of the way I'm using paramiko every time a command runs I'm getting the full console output i.e. all the stuff the appears when you login over SSH in my output. To slim that down and only display the output I'm interested in (the result of the command I've run). I'm trying to use the string slicing method.

My code will check the output initially for the presence of `:~$` using string.find() as the first intstance it will find will be just before the command runs I'm using that as the start point for the slice. At the minute I'm only looking to get rid of the output before the `:~$`. I'll probably then pass the result of the first slice to a new string and then look for `user@` in that string as the end point for the slice.

The issue I'm having is that once I've sliced the string I get no output whatsoever. Sometimes I'll get an output and that does appear to be correct in that its what I'm expecting to happen but most of the time I'm getting no output and sometime if I check the length of the string it will come back to say there are a number of characters in there but I get no output when I try to print the variable (`rem1`).

Below is my code, I'm issuing a command and then looping the script repeatedly until I either pick up on a second `:~$` in the output indicating the command has finised running or until there is nothing in the output variable. On each loop the contents of `output` is transfered to `final_output` which I use as the full string to manipulate at the end.

This may be a long winded way of doing what I want to do but honestly I couldn't think of another way round it as I kept running into issues when trying to use interactive commands like `apt full-upgrade`

```
def interactive_command(connect, ip_addr, port, uname, passwd, admin, issue_cmd):
    affirmative = {'yes', 'y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'ye', 'Ye', ''}
    connect.connect(ip_addr, port, uname, passwd)
    channel = connect.invoke_shell()
    channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
    stdin = channel.makefile('wb')

    channel.send(issue_cmd + '\n')

    if admin != -1:
        print('Sudo detected. Attempting to elevate privileges...')
        channel.send(passwd + '\n')
    else:
        pass

    fin_check = {':~$', ':~ $'}
    ser_check = {'[Y/n]', '(Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?'}
    counter = 0
    prompt_count = 0

    running = True
    monitoring = False
    final_output = ''

    while running:
        stdin
        counter = counter + 1
        #print('Loop Counter: ' + str(counter))

        # allow for 10 while loops to be completed before raising an error.

        if counter == 10:
            print('Unable to establish whether the command has finished running')
            running = False
            print('Counter: ' + str(counter))
            print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))

        #print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))
        sleep(2)
        if channel.recv_ready():
            output = channel.recv(65535).decode('utf-8')
        else:
            running = False
            monitoring = False
            print('No output detected. Printing last output.')
            break

        final_output = final_output + output
       #print(len(output))

        search = str(output)
        finish = -1

        if search == -1 or finish == -1:
            for y in ser_check:
                search = str(output).find(y)

                if search != -1:
                    print(output)
                    resp = input('Response?: ') + '\n'
                    channel.send(resp)
                    running = False
                    monitoring = True
            next

            for x in fin_check:
                if x in output:
                    prompt_count = prompt_count + 1
                    #print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))
                if prompt_count == 2:
                    finish = 1
                    break
                else:
                    finish = -1

                if finish != -1:
                    print('Command Finished')
                    #print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))
                    running = False
                    if monitoring:
                        pass
                    else:
                       # print(output)
                        break
            next
        sleep(3)

        while monitoring:
            output = channel.recv(65535).decode('utf-8')
            final_output = final_output + output
            for x in fin_check:
                if x in output:
                    prompt_count = prompt_count + 1
                    #print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))
                if prompt_count == 2:
                    finish = 1
                else:
                    finish = -1

                if finish != -1:
                    print('Command Finished')
                    #print('Prompt Count: ' + str(prompt_count))
                    running = False
                    monitoring = False
                    #print(output)
            next
        if prompt_count == 2:
            print('Prompt Count Reached. Command Finished')
            break
        sleep(3)

    print()

    #print(final_output)

    for c in fin_check:
        start_point = final_output.find(c)

        if start_point == -1:
            pass
        else:
            #print(len(final_output))
            #print(start_point)
            start_point = start_point + len(c)
            #print(start_point)
    next

    rem1 = final_output[start_point:]
    print(len(rem1))
    print(rem1)

    print()

    complete = input('Are you finished with this connection? ')

    if complete in affirmative:
        complete = 'Y'

    return complete
```

Comment: If you're doing this for fun/learning, then all the power to you. If you're doing this out of necessity because you can't find a tool that will do it for you, you should really look into [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works)

Comment: @vulpxn its a bit of both really. I've got enough Pi's running all the time that it can be a pain to update them all or remember to check there's no issues that I need to something to streamline the process and I want to improve my programming skills. I've seen Ansible in the past and it looks like it does all the things I want to do but correct me if I'm wrong it's a pay only product? And I while I have enough Pi's to be a pain I don't think I have enough to look at paying for that kind of enterprise solution.

Comment: Ansible is free & open-source, you might be referring to the Red Hat Enterprise version which is called Ansible Tower--that one does cost. Ansible is very handy once you understand the way in which it works, since you write your "scripts" using easy-to-read YAML files. Furthermore, it has the advantage of being *declarative* rather than *imperative*, so you really just tell it **the state you want your system to be in** and it will try everything it can to achieve it. Makes handling errors and multiple re-runs a breeze. I would highly recommend it.

Comment: @vulpxn ahh, you know all the times I've seen Ansible in articles and looked at the website I've never managed to twig to that fact. I've always seen the RHEL pages and the pricing button and some how always managed to miss the GitHub page for it (a bit embarassing really! :$). I'll definately have a look at it, as that'll make things a lot easier. :) If yourself or anyone else does have any ideas about my python problem though any help would be much appreciated as I'm curious to know where it's gone wrong. It seems like a simple function but somethings causing it to go on the fritz.